# How to grep for new folders which don't match folders from the pattern

Tags: bash

I need to do the following in bash:

Go to the folder and recursively check for new files in the current folder, new are the files with last update time >=D - 7 days, remember the name of every new files

I will do it like this: `find ./ -type f -ctime -7 -exec ls {} \; > new.files`

Then I need to go to previous directory `cd ../` and find for new folders created which are not from my white list (the list of folders) and were updated during last 7 days. If I will find any directory I need to go to this directory and do check for new files like I did it before (`find ./ -type f -ctime -7 -exec ls {} \; > new.files.from.new.dir`)

As the result I should send the list of new files and the list of new directories (not from the white list) with new files.

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: what's the name of your folder white list?  This is separate from new.files, I presume?

Comment: I've edited the question to add code tags.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the finished, refined script!  Note the cool use of redirection. :)

```
#!/bin/bash

#####################
#
# File change finder
#
####################

#export for use in shells!
export CURR_DIR=`pwd`

RESULTS_LOC=$CURR_DIR
WHITELISTS_LOC=$CURR_DIR
PERIOD=0.1
#Before X number of days... can be fractional
#also, needed for shells, hence source
export FTIME=-$PERIOD

#Make list of new files in current dir.
if [ -e $WHITELISTS_LOC/whitelist.files ]; then

    # What's going on here:
    #
    # 1. Inner shells change to current dir., then search for change files, w
    #    all three diff. types of mods.
    #
    # 2. The output is then sorted, and piped to a uniq -d to give only single 
    #    items for all duplicates.  This is then merged with a duplicate set 
    #    of calls that gives all uniq items via uniq -u.
    #
    # 3. Lastly, we apply any pertinent grep file filters to remove (-v -f)
    #    as in the case of the whitelist, or to select (as in the case of 
    #    our new dir.

    ((sort <(cd $CURR_DIR && find . -type f -ctime $FTIME) \
    <(cd $CURR_DIR && find . -type f -atime $FTIME) \
    <(cd $CURR_DIR && find . -type f -mtime $FTIME) | uniq -d) && \
    (sort <(cd $CURR_DIR && find . -type f -ctime $FTIME) \
    <(cd $CURR_DIR && find . -type f -atime $FTIME) \
    <(cd $CURR_DIR && find . -type f -mtime $FTIME) | uniq -u))| \
    grep -v -f $WHITELISTS_LOC/whitelist.files > \
    $CURR_DIR/new.files
else
    ((sort <(cd $CURR_DIR && find . -type f -ctime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $CURR_DIR && find . -type f -atime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $CURR_DIR && find . -type f -mtime $FTIME) | uniq -d) && \
        (sort <(cd $CURR_DIR && find . -type f -ctime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $CURR_DIR && find . -type f -atime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $CURR_DIR && find . -type f -mtime $FTIME) | uniq -u)) > \
    $CURR_DIR/new.files
fi

#Go down a dir, as requested
cd ../
WORKING_DIR=`pwd`

#Store list of new dirs (can be removed later, if desired.
((sort <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type d -ctime $FTIME) \
    <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type d -atime $FTIME) \
    <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type d -mtime $FTIME) | uniq -d) && \
    (sort <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type d -ctime $FTIME) \
    <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type d -atime $FTIME) \
    <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type d -mtime $FTIME) | uniq -u)) > \
    $RESULTS_LOC/new.dir

#Safely select for conditions based on whether whitelist file and new.dir
#file exist.
#
#This gives the result you want -- new files in new dirs.
if [ -e $WHITELISTS_LOC/whitelist.dir ]; then
    if [ -e $RESULTS_LOC/new.dir ]; then
    echo "1"
    ((sort <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -ctime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -atime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -mtime $FTIME) | uniq -d) && \
        (sort <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -ctime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -atime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -mtime $FTIME) | uniq -u)) |
    grep -f $RESULTS_LOC/new.dir \
        grep -v -f $WHITELISTS_LOC/whitelist.files > \
        $RESULTS_LOC/new.files.from.new.dir
    else
    echo "2"    
    ((sort <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -ctime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -atime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -mtime $FTIME) | uniq -d) && \
        (sort <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -ctime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -atime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -mtime $FTIME) | uniq -u)) |\
        grep -v -f $WHITELISTS_LOC/whitelist.files > \
        $RESULTS_LOC/new.files.from.new.dir
    fi
else
    if [ -e $RESULTS_LOC/new.dir ]; then
    echo "3"
    ((sort <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -ctime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -atime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -mtime $FTIME) | uniq -d) && \
        (sort <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -ctime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -atime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -mtime $FTIME) | uniq -u)) | \
        grep -f $RESULTS_LOC/new.dir > \
        $RESULTS_LOC/new.files.from.new.dir
    else
    echo "4"
    ((sort <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -ctime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -atime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -mtime $FTIME) | uniq -d) && \
        (sort <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -ctime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -atime $FTIME) \
        <(cd $WORKING_DIR && find . -type f -mtime $FTIME) | uniq -u)) > \
        $RESULTS_LOC/new.files.from.new.dir
    fi
fi
```

...sorry the version I posted earlier was non-working, but I made up for it with the super-cool new version, building on the basic idea from my original.

Comment: ./check.sh: line 9: WHITELISTS_LOC: command not found
find: missing argument to `-exec'
find: missing argument to `-exec'
./check.sh: line 19: WHITELISTS_LOC: command not found
find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: See the new script... it is corrected.  Your `-exec` command was missing information... it was unnecessary anyhow, so I just removed it :)

Comment: Thank you very much!
But I don't have whilte list of files.

Comment: It's optional... you don't need to use it unless you want to! :)

Comment: How to send emails with the list of new files to needed persons? )

Comment: Can I contact you directly? :)

Comment: Uh, wait what do you need? :)  Why not just type it out here?

Comment: Thank you for your great script!
I need to do the following:
1. Go to the folder "/test/incorrect"-> recursively check for new files in the current folder: new are the files with last update time since current date - 7 days -> remember every new files
2. go to the initial folder: .../test/
3. If there is a new folder(s) in the current folder (/test/) and if the folder(s) are not from white list-> go into each folder and recursively check for new files in the each folder (like at 1.)
If there are no new folders -> sent info about saved new files.

Comment: JasonR.Mick : s/he needs someone to provide unpaid consulting services. I'm upvoting your answer, because you clearly went overboard trying to help. (I'm a little skeptical about your solution, I'd really be surprised if you need to surround each 'block' in `(( ... ))` for starters). Maybe user1259103 will accept your answer, and when they get more reputation points, come back and upvote your answer, but don't count on it. Maybe @user1259103 will then post a 2nd question showing some attempt at actually solving their problem. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter Hi, skepticism is okay, but I actually tested this in `Centos 6`, using the above script, called within a standard `bash` shell.  There may be an alternative syntax to the nested parantheses, but as I'm `<` multiple find results into my sort, if I remove the inner parantheses, it will break the script (according to my testing).  Again, it might not be the most beautiful syntax and there may be some sort of unknown failure conditions due to my own knowledge limitations, but I tested it before I said it works here. Try it for yourself!!  Don't be an unfounded skeptic! :)

Comment: e.g. `sort < (...) < (...)` works, but `sort < ... < ...` does not, based on my testing.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to imply I didn't think your code would work. Given the care that was taken creating your code, I was pretty sure it would work. My major quibble is with your use of dbl-parens which are for arithmetic operations. See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html . Are you thinking of sub-shells, which are single-parened grouping? Good luck and keep posting.